# Terraform loop kubernetes manifest

Tags: kubernetes, terraform

I have a module with a kubernetes manifest resource like this example my main.tf inside provisioning-aks folder:

```
    resource "kubernetes_manifest" "test" {
      manifest = yamldecode(file("${path.module}/config.yml"))
    }
```

I have folder k8S, and inside this folder two others folders elk and ingest with yaml files inside them. How I can iterate over all this yaml file inside my module ?

```
├── k8s
│   ├── elk
│   │   ├── elasticsearch.yaml
│   │   ├── filebeat-ttfe.yaml
│   │   ├── filebeat.yaml
│   │   └── kibana.yaml
│   └── ingest
│       ├── filebeat-ingest-eventhub.yaml
│       ├── filebeat-ingest-http.yaml
│       ├── filebeat-ingest.yaml
│       └── logstash.yaml
├── main.tf
├── modules
│   ├── provisioning-aks
│   │   └── main.tf
```

Thanks.

Comment: could you please share the directory structure with the command `tree` for a better answer.

Comment: You could use something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/68505505/3248158

Answer (score 1):

I answer myself, it's how I dit it

```
resource "kubernetes_manifest" "provisioning" {
  for_each = fileset("", "k8s/{elk,ingest}/*.yaml")
  manifest = yamldecode(file(each.value))
}
```